# Bootstrap Container Class Not Taking Up Full Width Mobile Devices

Tags: css, mobile, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I have a registration form I am trying to make more user friendly for mobile devices.  I'm using Bootstrap 4 and trying to get my registration form to take up the full width of the screen for smaller devices like iPhones, etc., I have used the appropriate container class name for the div containing my row and form.  And I have given my form a class of 'col' so it takes up the full width.  But the problem is the container.  And when I try and target the breakpoint in my child theme's style sheet, I am not able to affect the container.  How can I get the container to stretch 100% of the width of smaller devices?  I am using the Ocean-WP child theme. You can view the page in question on a mobile device at the following link: http://www.statesoccerpass.com/player-registration-page/

```
<div class="container" style="border: 2px solid green;">
        <h1 id="page_title">Player Registration Page</h1>
        <?php echo $season_text ?>
            <!-- <div class="row"><?php //display_progress(1);?></div> -->
                <div class = "row">

                    <form style="border: 2px solid yellow;" class= "col" id = "player_info" name="player_info" action="http://www.statesoccerpass.com/index.php/player-registration-step-2/" method="post">  

                        <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <span>Passes are valid for both Fall 2018<?php echo $season_year_start_text; ?> and Spring 2019<?php echo $season_year_end_text; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Player passes expire July 31, 2019<?php echo $this_season_end->format('n/j/Y'); ?><br /><br />Can't find your team? If your team is new for this fall, please remind your coach to register the team so that players can register.  <br /><br/>
                        </span>

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                                <label class="col-sm col-lg-2" for="league_id">1. Select your league</label>
                                <select class= "col-sm col-lg-10" id = "league_id" name="league_id" size="1" style="width: 304px;" onchange=""  tabindex = "2" >
                                    <option value='a' selected> -- </option>
                                    <?php echo display_active_leagues_select()?>
                                </select>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                                <label class="col-sm col-lg-2" for="division_id">2. Select your division</label>
                                <select class="col-sm col-lg-10" id="division_id" name="division_id" size="1" style="width: 304px;"  tabindex = "2" >
                                    <option  value='a' selected> -- </option>
                                    <!--insert divisions here via ajax -->
                                </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                                <label class="col-sm col-lg-2" for="team_id">3. Select the team you want to join</label>
                                <select class="col-sm" id="team_id" name="team_id" size="1" style="width: 304px;"  tabindex = "3" >
                                    <option value='a' selected> -- </option>
                                    <!-- insert teams here via ajax --> 
                                </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                                <label class="col-sm col-lg-2" for="player_first_name">Enter your first name</label>
                                <input class="col-sm" type="text" name="player_first_name" id = "player_first_name" tabindex = "4" style="width: 300px;"> 
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                                <label class="col-sm col-lg-2" for="player_middle_name">Enter your middle name</label>
                                <input class="col-sm" type="text" name="player_middle_name" id="player_middle_name" tabindex = "5" style="width: 300px;"> 
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                                <label class="col-sm col-lg-2" for="player_last_name">Enter your last name</label>
                                <input class="col-sm" type="text" name="player_last_name" id="player_last_name" tabindex = "6" required style="width: 300px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" style = 'font-size: 12pt;'>You must have a matching government issued picture ID.</div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid green;">   
                                <label class="col" for="player_birth_month" >Enter your date of birth (Month/Day/Year)</label>

                                <div class="col-sm col-lg-6" style="border: 2px solid red;margin:0 auto;">

                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 2px solid;display:inline;">
                                    <label class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1" for="player_day_month" >Month</label>
                                        <select class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1" name="player_birth_month" id="player_birth_month" required tabindex = "13">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <?php select_month_input()?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid;display:inline;">
                                        <label class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1" for="player_day_month" >Day</label>
                                        <select class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1" name="player_birth_day" id="player_birth_day" required tabindex = "14">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                        <?php select_day_input()?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group" style="border: 2px solid;display:inline;">
                                        <label class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1" for="player_year_month" >Year</label>
                                        <select class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1" name="player_birth_year" id="player_birth_year" required tabindex = "15">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                        <?php select_birthyear_input()?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name = "product_id" value="0" />
                                <input type="hidden" id = "product_type" name = "product_type" value="player_signup" />
                                <input type="submit" style="font-size:24px; color:#0000FF;" value="Continue" tabindex = "20">
                            </fieldset>
                            </form>
                    </div><!--end form row-->
            <?php
            //echo "<br/>Session user_id: " .get_session_value('user_id');
            require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cart/cart-footer.php';
            require_once  $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/user-footer.php';
            ?>
            <?php display_admin_footer(); ?>
    </div><!--end bootstrap container div -->
```

My media query:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container{
        max-width:100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want full width the container-fluid makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing the `class="container"` entirely. Your row class is holding the page content together on larger devices. Not best practice but you won't have to battle the other columns that are collapsing too.

Example:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid green;">
    <h1 id="page_title">Player Registration Page</h1>
    <?php echo $season_text ?>
        <!-- <div class="row"><?php //display_progress(1);?></div> -->
            <div class = "row">
```

In the link example provided above I changed this line:

```
<div id="content-wrap" class="container clr">
```

to

```
<div id="content-wrap" class="clr">
```

You have two containers (one higher on the page and your green line example) declared that are fighting each other. Remove either one and it should work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  Take a look at the page now.  Didn't stretch.

Comment: Is  your goal to get each form element to span the entire page with no padding? Because, the example looks good to me with 15px on either side.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container{
        max-width:100% !important;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your input Martynas Martin but setting the padding of the container to 0px did not affect the width of the container at all.

Comment: Interesting, if I remove padding on Dev tools it does go full width

Comment: I have to go to work now, but the last change I made was your suggestion.  So if you inspect element you should see the padding set to 0.  Check your iPhone or whatever mobile device.  You should see the container has not stretched to the full width of the screen.  I'm miffed.

Comment: I just checked and .container is still 15px, maybe something is setting it back, check your css structure

Comment: Other thing you could do is just remove .container and use some padding/margin on bigger screens to give some breathing space.